# Query Mongo for all entries added today (newbie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query Mongo for all entries added today. For example, if I added something at 9 am, I only want that back and not something added at 9 pm last night.

I'm unsure how to properly format the query.

```
const db = require('../models');
const now = new Date();
const startOfToday = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

// Defining methods for the mealsController

module.exports = {

   find(req, res) {
    db
      .Meal
      .find({created_on: {$gte: startOfToday}})
  },
  findAll(req, res) {
     db
      .Meal
      .find(req.query)
      .sort({ date: -1 })
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
   },
  findById(req, res) {
     db
       .Meal
       .findById(req.params.id)
       .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
       .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
```

Comment: can you please share what error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with a precise query if you share how you are storing data in db.
From your question, what i am guessing you are looking for is retrieving documents inserted after a certain time.
`ObjectId.getTimestamp()` will help you in this case. in Mongo, every insert has a time stamp associated with it. eg. 
`ObjectId("5a6d75590827a11b6016f470").getTimestamp()`
returned

```
ISODate("2018-01-28T07:01:45Z")
```

To get the Object id of a document, 
`var a = db.collection.find(<condition>).toArray();`
`a[0]._id` then prints `ObjectId("5a6d75560827a11b6016f46e")`
so you can compare which documents were inserted after a certain date or time using this.

GL :)